# POSTMAN - Schema validation is passed even for incorrect test data

Tags: json, schema, postman

tests["validating schema "] = tv4.validate(testdata, schema) is passed even if "code" and  "status" missing in test data. How to make sure that response and test data schema both are matching for JSON schema.

```
  var testdata={
"csosProfileDataList": [
{
  "profileName": "cameron test",
  "deaRegisteredName": "COLISEUM SAME DAY SURG CTR#712",
  "deaLicenseNo": "BP6117004",
},
{
  "profileName": "Vaseem!@#$%%",
  "code": 69022,
  "deaRegisteredName": "COLISEUM SAME DAY SURG CTR#712",
  "deaLicenseNo": "BP6117004",
  "status": "COMPLETE"
}
]
};

 var schema={
"type":"object",
"properties":{
"csosProfileData":{
    "type":"array",
    "items":{
        "type":"object", 
    "properties":{
    "profileName":{"type":"string"},
    "code":{"type":"string"},
    "deaRegistrationName":{"type":"string"},
    "deaLicenseNo":{"type":"string"},
    "status":{"type":"string"}
},
 "required":["profileName", "code", "deaRegistrationName", "deaLicenseNo", "status"]
    }

}
}

};
tests["validating schema "] = tv4.validate(testdata, schema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your schema has a couple spelling mistakes in it which is why it is not validating correctly. Due to the misspelling, the validator was not using the item information to validate and was only validating that the root was an object.  I've included an updated schema.

```
let schema = {
"type":"object",
"required" : ["csosProfileDataList"],
"properties":{
    "csosProfileDataList":{
        "type":"array", 
        "items" : [{
            "type":"object",
            "required":["profileName", "code", "deaRegisteredName", "deaLicenseNo", "status"],
            "properties":{
                "profileName":{"type":"string"},
                "code":{"type":"string"},
                "deaRegisteredName":{"type":"string"},
                "deaLicenseNo":{"type":"string"},
                "status":{"type":"string"}
            }
        }]
    }
}};
```

When testing I usually add some logging after my test so I can see where it might be failing

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(tv4));
```